# generate timestamp without time vs. mid-night timestamp

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, sql-timestamp

I'm going to generate timestamp from a date

```
set @inputDate = '2016-04-21';
select timestamp(@inputDate) from dual;
```

the result is:

```
2016-04-21 00:00:00
```

like midnight time. How can I know that the input file was generated without time or it's midnight timestamp?

Comment: If keep that distinction is important, you create a flag, the one you create from a date without out time have `1` the one with time `2`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropezaThanks for the answer, you right it's a good solution but I should keep it in the database. Hence, I'm looking for another solution from data-time logic in MySql database engine instead of saving the flag in the database.

Comment: I dont see how you can difference between both without a flag.